# How to unselect all radio button in radio group using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, codiqa

I designed my mobile application using Codiqa. So all css and js are loading from the link. I don't know how to uncheck all radio buttons in a radiobutton list. I tried many coding but its not working for me. 
HTML:

```
       <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-controltype="radiobuttons">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
              <legend>
                  Shift
              </legend>
              <input id="radio1" name="rbtnShift" value="1" data-theme="c" type="radio">
              <label for="radio1">
                  AM
              </label>
              <input id="radio2" name="rbtnShift" value="2" data-theme="c" type="radio">
              <label for="radio2">
                  PM
              </label>
              <input id="radio3" name="rbtnShift" value="3" data-theme="c" type="radio">
              <label for="radio3">
                  Night
              </label>
          </fieldset>
      </div>
```

Jquery:

```
  $("input:radio[name='rbtnShift']").each(function (i) {        
        this.checked = false;
    });
```

I tried above coding but its not working for me. I'm certainly missing something basic, but I can't figure out what is the problem.

First, I select a option

[image]

After button click, it showing the same like given below

[image]

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/3r8SC/. Maybe Codiqua changes things, though.

Comment: is there other jquery errors ? try to alert a value inside document.ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using knockout.js, below code for unselect all radio buttons in a list

```
 $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio();         
 $("input[name^='rbtnShift']").attr("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Use below code for dynamically selecting a radio buttons in a list,

```
$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio();           
$("input[name=rbtnShift][value=" + 1 + "]").prop('checked', true);
$("input[name^='rbtnShift']").attr("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can give them a `classname` and try:

```
$('.classname').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Hi kanishka, thanks for your reply. This is a mobile application so its designed in Codiqa. The class and js are dynamically loading from the link. I tried this also. but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this also;

```
$('input:radio[name="rbtnShift"]').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: Hi firnas, its also not working for me. I don't know why all the codes are not working for me?

Comment: If there is no error, then there is nothing wrong in your code. However, there might be another code that does this purposely. Try to trigger and see where it happens, may be you can debug.